activeadmin with rails 7 bad behavior
I tried to upgrade from rails 6 to 7 and I faced unexpected behavoir from activeadmin configuration
active_admin.rb file
  config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :default do |menu|
      menu.add label: 'Sidekiq',
               url: '/admin/sidekiq', html_options: { target: :blank },
               if: proc { current_admin_user.full_permissions? },
               priority: 14
    end
    admin.download_links = proc {       
      current_admin_user.full_permissions? 
    }
  end

application_controller.rb
  def access_denied(_exception)    
    flash['Not Authorized']
    sign_out_and_redirect(user)
  end

the issue is that when admin.download_links proc invoke and 'current_admin_user.full_permissions? ' return false active admin invoke access_denied method at application controller which is not the same behavior at rails 6
rails version is 7.0.3
activeadmin 3.1.0
ruby version 3.2.0
